# How to do whatsapp like animation for attachment in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewanimation

i am trying to implement the animation similar to whatsapp attachment . I mean the view animation when we tap the attachment button. Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the action of the attachment button, add the following code, the animation is already set.

```
- (IBAction)onbtnTapped:(id)sender {

    self.view1.frame = CGRectMake( _btn1.frame.origin.x+_btn1.frame.size.width, _btn1.frame.origin.y+_btn1.frame.size.height, 0, 0);

    self.view1.hidden=NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];

    self.view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 1, 1);
    self.view1.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 100];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0];
    animation.duration = 0.5;
    [self.view1.layer setCornerRadius: 0];
    [self.view1.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom `UIView` with the several `UIButton` which you required and then you can show or hide the `UIView` as per your requirements.